# search for substring in output, then print the line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to list a file and then search the lines for a pattern, like I do in Bash with.

```
cat /etc/passwd | grep nologin
```

I try the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import subprocess

CMD=('cat', '/etc/passwd')
SEARCH="nologin"
PIPE_ERG=subprocess.Popen(CMD , stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
OUTPUT = PIPE_ERG.communicate()[0].splitlines()
for LINE in OUTPUT:
  if SEARCH in LINE:
    print(LINE)
```

If I execute the script with python3 I always get this errormessage:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./pipe2.py", line 11, in <module>
    if SEARCH in LINE:
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

When I just print the lines without search, the script will list all my lines.

How do I get each line with the pattern "nologin" from the output?

Comment: Later on 'cat' will be replaced by a ldbsearch-command and the result will be stored in a file, that's why I can't just open a file, but this is an easy example to explain what I need ;-)

Comment: by the way, it works with python2 but not with python3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like in Python 3, [`PIPE_ERG.communicate()[0]`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) is not a `str`, but `bytes`, and for `bytes`, the `in` operator is not defined. You have to convert those `bytes` to `str` first. The simplest way would be just to do `LINE = str(LINE)` in the loop, or use `LINE.decode()`:

```
for LINE in OUTPUT:
    LINE = LINE.decode()
    if SEARCH in LINE:
        print(LINE)
```

Or use `Popen` with [`universal_newlines=True`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output):

```
PIPE_ERG=subprocess.Popen(CMD , stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
```

From the documentation:

> By default, this function will return the data as encoded bytes. The
>   actual encoding of the output data may depend on the command being
>   invoked, so the decoding to text will often need to be handled at the
>   application level.
>
> This behaviour may be overridden by setting universal_newlines to True